# XPages Designer: ClassPath in project settings reverts back several times per day

Tags: java, xpages, sourcetree, eclipse-classpath

In the Project Properties box, under Java Build path, I added two resources: a src folder and a Jar. That works for several hours, no errors when I do a clean build. But then, all of a sudden, these two resources disappear and I get 52 Java errors. So I add them back again, recompile: no errors.

Some info:

- latest Domino Designer afaik
- I develop on local, the db is replicated manually to the test server
- there is no separate template db (yet)
- the development db is also the test db
- I use an On-Disk Project on my system (local, no git)
- I also installed and use SourceTree (just to be able to move back)
- afaik nobody but me touches the project settings
- more strange things happen (they seem irrelevant to me at the moment)

I assume something goes wrong while syncing the NSF with the ODP. I sometimes get warnings that some elements are out of sync, but I don't really understand why.

How can this happen, or better: how can I repair this behaviour?

Comment: I swapped one problem for another: I switched off source control, but that also means SourceTree is out, Bummer :(

Comment: Even without source control (no SourceTree, no ODP), this error keep on coming, once every 2-3 days or so. Some day I'll create myself a nice template db...

Comment: Over a year later: it still happens, but less often. One day, everything works fine, the next day, when I open the db in the Designer, the source folder is gone and the jar has vanished.